# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 3 of type Ambiguous constructor argument types

Tags: java, spring, constructor

This error occurs when loading my Spring application. I have checked all the constructor arguments for the corresponding bean (PerformanceSchedulePoster). Here I used five constructor arguments and all the five constructors arguments are of different type. Can any one help me in resolving the dependency issue. I have attached the log below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.enttek.unified.rest.server.handler.AssembledMethodHandlerFactory#111bcbb' defined in class path resource [spring/imports/backOfficeWebServices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'PerformanceSchedulePoster' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'PerformanceSchedulePoster' defined in class path resource 

[spring/imports/backOfficeWebServices-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 3 of type [com.enttek.framework.util.plugin.ServiceFactory]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
        ... 138 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'PerformanceSchedulePoster' defined in class path resource [spring/imports/backOfficeWebServices-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 3 of type [com.enttek.framework.util.plugin.ServiceFactory]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:716)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 146 more
```

Comment: please format your code properly ;)

Comment: Post how you initialize the bean

Comment: And the bean constructors :)

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), without that we cannot tell you more, then log says...

Comment: Add your bean definitions and related config files(xml, java)

Comment: This error does not occurs in my dev environment. It occurs only in production environment (while upgrading my production application)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you get this type of error.. Kindly refer the Field name used in the repository and Field name in Service layer are same with the Entity field name.

For Example,
I declare field name in entity as `userFullInfo`
and I used and defined in repository as `userInfo`
and Called in service layer as `repository.findByUserInfo_Id();`
then you get these type of errors.

So you just check the argument type used in entity, repository and service.